The conditional probability of the complement
An investigator is 60% convinced that a suspect is guilty of the crime. Assuming it was found that the real criminal is bald, that 20% of the population is bald and that the suspect is bald, in order to find out now how much the investigator should be convinced the suspect is guilty now, we can calculate:
Let $ G $ be the event that the suspect is guilty, and $ C $ be the event that the characteristic applies to the suspect.
Then:
$ P(G | C) = \frac{P(G \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(C | G)P(G)}{P(C | G)P(G) + P(C | G^C)P(G^C)} = \frac{1 \times 0.6}{1 \times 0.6 +0.2\times0.4} $.
I understand why $ P(C | G) = 1 $, because if the suspect is guilty, he must be bald.
But I don't understand why $ P(C | G^c) = 0.2 $. After all, we are given that the suspect is bald, so it doesn't matter whether they are guilty or not.

I think the population is assume large enough (or infinite) so that $P(C)$ and $P(C\mid G^C)$ are essentially the same.

This sort of set up is always problematic because it assumes no correlation between the reasons the investigator set the prior probabilities and the trait.  Here, for instance, there are obvious problems:  suppose the nature of the crime has lead the investigator to near certainty that the perpetrator is an older male.  Well, being an older male is highly correlated with being bald, and that correlation must be factored in.
